# How to solve this in LINQ query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I was working on MVC3 project. I need help writting Linq expression. My model is something like this.

**Model Class**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DetCount { get; set; }
```

I need to do something like this,

```
DetCount = (from sel in db.PoDetails where sel.PoId == Id select sel).Count();  // Id is current model Id.
```

Based on the parent table Id, i need to get the child table records count.

**Example**

Parent Table

```
 Id                  Name

  1                   XYZ
  2                   ABC
```

Child Table

```
Id         P_Id

 1          1
 2          1
 3          2


DetCount = (from sel in db.child where sel.P_Id == Id select sel).Count(); // if Id= 1
```

**Result**

```
DetCount = 2;
```

I have written the code something like this.

**Code**

```
model = ...
select new porders
                     {
                         Id = p.Id,  //This Id is passed to next statement for DetCount.
                         DetCount = (from sel in db.PoDetails where sel.PoId == Id select sel).Count();    // I need to pass value from another linq query.
                      }
```

Please help me for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = select new porders
                 {
                     Id = p.Id,
                     PODate = p.Date.Value,
                     RefNo = p.RefNo,
                     Status = resloc.Description,
                     Supplier = resstat.Name,
                     DetCount = db.PoDetails
                      .Select(p => p.sel)
                        .Where(sel.PoId == asd.Id).Count() 
                  }
```

Comment: @G . R: How can i use the current Id apart from using asd.Id

Comment: I need to pass the current Id here, db.PoDetails
                      .Select(p => p.Id)
                        .Where(p.PoId == Id).Count()

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the count you want? If so this should work:

```
var DetCount = db.PoDetails.Where(sel=>sel.PoId == Id).Count();  // Id is current model Id.
```

Cheers :)